# Spurious dtrace user stack traces?

Tags: solaris, solaris-10, dtrace

I am using dtrace to sample stack traces of a process like this:

```
# /usr/sbin/dtrace -p $MYPID -x ustackframes=100 stack.d -s -o stack.log
```

Where `stack.d` looks like:

```
profile-99
/execname == "mybinary"/
{
    @[execname, ustack()] = count();
}
```

I am adding `-p` to `dtrace` such that it has the symbols during stack writing even when the user process has already exited.

This works - but I observe 3 issues:

During tracing I regularly get error messages like:

```
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 12345: profile:::profile-99):\
  invalid address (0x0) in action #3
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 12345: profile:::profile-99):\
  invalid address (0xffffffff00000000) in action #3
dtrace: error on enabled probe ID 1 (ID 12345: profile:::profile-99):\
  invalid address (0x7ffe8000) in action #3
[..]
```

(i.e. many of those)

What is the underlying issue there?

The process executes like it should (i.e. no crashes).

The other thing is that a lot of recorded stacks don't contain any symbols at all.

What are possible reasons for such symbol-less stacks?

Also - some stacks do not start with `_start -> main` but still contain symbols (i.e. with function from the binary).

Are those incomplete stacks ones where dtrace somehow failed to get to the bottom?

Comment: How up-to-date is your system?  Searching for `dtrace ustack invalid address` results in hits with several mentions of stack tracing bugs in various earlier versions of dtrace.  Documentation for `ustack()` is here:  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-6223/chp-actsub-ustack/index.html  `ustackframes` defaults to 20, so by default the result of `ustack()` will be limited to 20 stack frames.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, as I wrote I am using `-x ustackframes=100`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, I am on Solaris 5.10 Generic_150400-18.